# Jquery: change Json source of Autocomplete Combobox widget?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

First of all i start with Jquery and my question is a little noobie but i didn't manage to find a solution.
I got the official Combobox example. I changed it to use a Json source.
But i want 2 instances of the combobox, with a different URL for the source.

(I think i dont need to create a second Combobox function only to change the source, tell me if im wrong)

Here's my code:

```
<div id="etape1">
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label>Veuillez selectionner une application: </label>
    <select id="combobox_application">
        <option value="">Select one...</option>
        <option value="Chargement en cours">Chargement en cours</option>

    </select>
</div>

<button id="create-user">Ajouter une application</button>
</div>
<div id="etape2" style="display:none">
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label>Veuillez selectionner un scenario: </label>
    <select id="combobox_scenario">
        <option value="">Select one...</option>
        <option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
        <option value="AppleScript">AppleScript</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

### EDIT

Thx for your help, unfortunately it dosn't work. I'm here:

- Got a jquery-combobox.js (source below)
- In my main page, got this:

  ```
  <script>
  $(function() {
  $('#combobox_application').combobox({
      source: function(req,add) {
          $.ajax({
              url: "?module=gestionApplication&action=getListeApplications",
              dataType:"json",
              success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
                  alert(data);
                  add(data);
              }
          });
      },
      selected: function(event, ui) {
          $("#etape2").css('display', 'block');
      }
  });
     $('#combobox_scenario').combobox({
      source: function(req,add) {
          $.ajax({
              url: "?module=gestionApplication&action=getListeScenarios",
              dataType:"json",
              success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
                  alert(data);
                  add(data);
              }
          });
      }
  });
  ```

jquery-combobox.js:

-

```
(function( $ ) {
$.widget( "ui.combobox", {
    _create: function() {
        var input,
            self = this,
            select = this.element.hide(),
            selected = select.children( ":selected" ),
            value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "",
            wrapper = this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
                .addClass( "ui-combobox" )
                .insertAfter( select );
        input = $( "<input>" )
            .appendTo( wrapper )
            .val( value )
            .addClass( "ui-state-default ui-combobox-input" )
            .autocomplete({
                delay: 0,
                minLength: 0,

                // Need define source in my main js
                //~ source: function( request, response ) {
                    //~ $.ajax({
                        //~ url: "?module=gestionApplication&action=getListeApplications",
                        //~ dataType: "json",

                        //~ success: function( data ) {
                            //~ response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                                //~ return {
                                    //~ label: item.nom,
                                    //~ value: item.nom,
                                    //~ option: this
                                //~ }
                            //~ }));
                        //~ }
                    //~ });
                //~ },
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    ui.item.option.selected = true;
                    self._trigger( "selected", event, {
                        item: ui.item.option
                    });
                },
                change: function( event, ui ) {
                    if ( !ui.item ) {
                        var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( $(this).val() ) + "$", "i" ),
                            valid = false;
                        select.children( "option" ).each(function() {
                            if ( $( this ).text().match( matcher ) ) {
                                this.selected = valid = true;
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                        if ( !valid ) {
                            // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                            $( this ).val( "" );
                            select.val( "" );
                            input.data( "autocomplete" ).term = "";
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            .addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" );

        input.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
                .appendTo( ul );
        };

        $( "<a>" )
            .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
            .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
            .appendTo( wrapper )
            .button({
                icons: {
                    primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                },
                text: false
            })
            .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
            .addClass( "ui-corner-right ui-combobox-toggle" )
            .click(function() {
                // close if already visible
                if ( input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" ) ) {
                    input.autocomplete( "close" );
                    return;
                }

                // work around a bug (likely same cause as #5265)
                $( this ).blur();

                // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
                input.focus();
            });
    },

    destroy: function() {
        this.wrapper.remove();
        this.element.show();
        $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call( this );
    }
});
})( jQuery );
```

But this dosn't work, selected is ok, but source seems to not change anything.

### Thx a lot for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn your code into a function (can house it in a separate file)

Then pass things like id, url & selected in when you call the function.

eg

```
 $(function() {

    createCombobox('#combobox_application','?module=gestionApplication&action=getListeApplications',
     function(event, ui) { $("#etape2").css('display', 'block');  }
    );

    createCombobox('#combobox_scenario','?module=gestionApplication&action=getListeScenarios')   

  });
```

**EDIT**

I think i understand your issue.

you've included the widget code on your page. You can have it in an extra .js file

You only need this

```
 $(function() {
   $('#combobox_application').combobox({  
        source: function(req,add) {  
                      $.ajax({  
                        url: "SOME_URL",  
                       dataType:"json",  
                       success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){  
                         add(data);  
                       }  
                   });  

        },  
        select: function(event, ui) {  
                       $("#etape2").css('display', 'block');
        }});  

   $('#combobox_scenario').combobox({  
        source: function(req,add) {  
                      $.ajax({  
                        url: "SOME_URL",  
                       dataType:"json",  
                       success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){  
                         add(data);  
                       }  
                   });  

        }}); 
    });
```

Don't forget to include the external .js file references

Comment: I'm a little confused with the 
(function( $ ) {
  $.widget( "ui.combobox", {

How can i put this into a function?